# Adding numbers based on 2 matrices according to a constraint matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, addition, cumsum

I have 2 matrices; Matrix A and Matrix B.

```
Matrix A = [1 3 6 2 7;
            2 1 5 3 4;
            8 3 7 2 1]

Matrix B = [0 0 1 0 0; 
            0 0 0 0 1;
            0 1 0 0 0]
```

and I want to check if the '1' in matrix `B` is placed in a place in matrix `A` where it is greater than or equal to `6` then leave it as it is. But if it is smaller than `6`, then go to the place of the number that is less than this number in matrix `A` and put a '1' in this place in matrix `B` and add the 2 numbers and recheck if the sum is equal to or greater than `6` and so on. 
As you can see in matrix `B` row 2 the `1` is put in the place of `4` in matrix `A`. Since the `4` is less than `6` then I will go to the second smaller number than the `4` which in this case is `3` and add `3` and `4` together. This will give us `7` which is greater than `6` so we will stop. So here for example the output matrix will be:

```
Matrix output = [0 0 1 0 0;
                 0 0 0 1 1;
                 0 1 0 1 1]
```

The steps:

Go to the number that is  just smaller than it. In this case go to 3 as it is the one that is just smaller than the 4. I can explain more:

1. check the place of the 1 in Matrix B and see its value in Matrix A.
2. If the number in Matrix A is greater than 6, leave it as it is and leave the 1 in Matrix B as it is and go to another row.
3. If the number in Matrix A is smaller than 6, then what we want is that we want add this number to another number and make it equal to or greater than 6.
4. This number is the one that is just smaller than it. For example if the row has [2 5 6 1 3] and the 1 is placed in the place of the 5 and 5 is less than the constraint. So we have to go to the 3 as it is the one that is just smaller than the 5 and add them together.
5. After adding them put 1's in the places of both numbers and check the constraints again. If it satisfies the constraint leave them and go to another row. If not go the one that is just smaller than the number again and do the same.

Thank you so much.

This code is working when matrix `B` is empty and it puts the 1 in the place of the highest number and it checks the constraint. If it is less than the number it will go to the second highest number and add and recheck and so on.. But what I want now is to solve it with predefined `0`s and `1`s

```
B=zeros(size(A));
for k=1:size(A,1)
a=A(k,:)
[b,ia]=sort(a,'descend')
    c=cumsum(b)
    jj=find(c>=6,1)
    idx=ia(1:jj)
B(k,idx)=1
end
```

Comment: can there be more than one 1's in the Matrix B?

Comment: so Say there are two 1's in Matrix B, and both are less than 6, both requires a common element to sum up to 6 - is it still a 1 for that element or is it a 2 ?

Comment: No no it is still a 1 it's a matrix of 0's and 1's

Comment: Why do you keep re-posting the same question over and over?

Comment: I don't understand? Where?

Comment: @Sassosamer You do realize that users with over 10k of reputation can see deleted questions, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one took a while, but I think I got it in the end...

Doing most of the process without loop except the final stage, plugging in the index row by row to change B which can be done by a arrayfun. I think there might be a few redundant steps, but I think it is pretty fast.

```
    C = A';
    D = B' > 0 ;
    E  = repmat(max(C(D),1),[1 size(A,2)]);
    F  = A-E<=0;
    G = A.*F;
    [H ind] = sort (G,2,'descend');
    I = (cumsum(H,2) >=6)*-1 +1;
    Indent = ones(size(A,1),1);
    J = [Indent I];
   K = J(:,1:size(A,2)).*ind;

   for t= 1:size(A,1)
       B(t,K(t,K(t,:)~=0)) = 1;
   end

>> B =

 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: A = [2 3 1 4 7;3 5 2 7 1;8 3 7 2 1]
B = [0 0 0 1 0;0 0 0 1 0;0 1 0 0 0]
 [r c] = size(A)
 for i = 1:r
     for j = 1:c
         if(B(i,j) == 1)
             if A(i,j) <= 6
                 P=A(i,:)
                 [b, ia] = sort(P(P<=P(j)),'descend')
                 c = cumsum(b)
                 jj = find(c>=6,1)
                 idx = ia(1:jj)
                 B(i,idx) = 1
             end
         end
     end
 end
I implemented this code and i dont know why is there a problem in the last row. Your code works perfectly fine but i wanted to try this. So can you help me?

Comment: my code does not use loops, if you want someone else to fix your loop for you, open a new post with the code properly formatted, and someone might be able to help.

Comment: @Sassosamer *"Your code works perfectly fine*: That's what that little "accept this solution" checkmark is for!